# Infinite Loop with my binary search implementation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, binary-search

this is my first question on stack overflow so please bear with me.
I wrote this binarySearch function and for some reason it hangs - I'm assuming because of an infinite loop. Can anyone find the faults with my code?

```
let binarySearch = (array, value) => {
 let target = value,
     start = 0,
     end = array.length - 1,
     middle = Math.floor( (end + start)/2 )

  while (start <= end){

    if ( array[middle] === target ){
      return true
    }else if (array[middle] < target){
      start = middle + 1
    }else if (array[middle] > target){
      end = middle - 1
    }    
  }
 return false
}
```

Comment: Notwithstanding whatever the bug is, a binary search algorithm should return the _index_ of the found item (and `undefined` or similar if not found), not just a boolean to say whether the value was found or not.

Comment: Have you considered maybe logging the values of `start`, `middle`, and `end` to see what might be going on?

Comment: I recommend adding Alert at the beginning of the while loop to check the values each pass. You will probably find the issue easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An infinite loop occurs because the implementation shown is an iterative binary search, but the `middle` value is not recalculated upon each iteration, as others have mentioned. Thus, the `middle` variable will never change beyond the first iteration.

Below is an implementation which returns the index of `value`, or `null`, if value is not found.

```
function binarySearch(array, value) {
  let middle, start = 0,
    end = array.length - 1;

  while (start <= end) {
    middle = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);

    if (array[middle] > value) {
      end = middle - 1;
    } else if (array[middle] < value) {
      start = middle + 1;
    } else {
      return middle;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: So obvious, yet I did not see it! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The most obvious bug is that you need to calculate `middle` as the first operation *inside* the loop, not outside of it.

Without that change, you're always examining whichever element was "middle" when the function was first called, and never partitioning your search space.

With that fix in place, my tests indicate that the code works as required, although as suggested in the comments you should be returning the index of the found element, not simply a flag to say whether the element was found or not.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for the tip. Also, what if you wanted to use binary search in a way just to see if the element exists? Can you elaborate on why it should always be the index?

Comment: @mega0319 because with a binary search you get the index "for free", at which point an existence test is just a test for `index < 0` or `index !== undefined`, depending on how you signal "not found".   By all means wrap that separate test into a function of its own, but if the binary search tells you the index, why throw that information away?